# Openpyxl not removing sheets completely from Excel Sheet

Tags: openpyxl

I was wondering if someone can explain why openpyxl is not removing sheet completely. I am using default openpyxl function. Thought this is deleting the sheet but the traces are still there in the developer tab. If you can help to fix this, I would be very grateful.

```
`remove_sheet(worksheet)`
```

While I am now using this alternative approach, but I beleive this is not efficient, since I first delete the sheet, then again use openpyxl to write it

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
book = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = file, ReadOnly=False)
xl.Application.Run("delSheets.delSheets")
book.Save()
book.Close()
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

[image]

Comment: I am assuming based on the screen shot that you removed one of the worksheets that is still showing up in the vba editor. Which sheet did you remove in your example?

Comment: Sheet11 to Sheet 19, then Sheet 20 onwards were all removed by openpyxl. Sheet2, Sheet100 is created by openpyxl. If I run the python script again and delete sheet100, it will show sheet100 as blank.

Comment: Can you post your actual code that you used to delete the worksheet. I tried deleting a worksheet with `remove_worksheet` and then went to the VBA editor and I didn't see the worksheet.